# Does it follow industry practice to use the term "mix" to refer to a different version of a song?

Tags: terminology, release, music-business, production, distribution

I am wondering if you could confirm with me if what I'm doing is correct:

I wrote a song, *Gotta Have You*, and I'm planning on releasing it next month as my debut single.

I will have 4 other versions of the song that I will include in my debut album, *Aviv Unleashed*:

1. Gotta Have You (Space Mix)
2. Gotta Have You (Psycho Mix)
3. Gotta Have You (Daybreak Mix)
4. Gotta Have You (Original Mix)

They are named with easy, memorable and meaningful identifiers.

Does this follow industry practice?

Does it follow industry practice to use the term "mix" to refer to a different version of a song?

Comment: I think this belongs on a different site, maybe [music.se] as about making /producing music

Comment: A mix usually has to do with using the same tracks and changing up the EQ or looping or other effects to make a different version of the same song. If its a different arrangement then I believe "mix" would be inappropriate.

Comment: @sanpaco Then what would the appropriate way to identify these different versions? the word _version_? like _Gotta Have You (Space Version)_ ... and _Gotta Have You (Original Version)_? I have to say _mix_ sounds better.

Comment: I'm not real an expert but if it were me I'd just call them "Space Version" etc

Answer (score 2):

The concept of a mix comes from the days of dub and disco when songs would be edited using mixing boards and tape to change the pace (especially in dub) or to change the length and ideal for mixing (especially in disco).  The concept of a remix is to take the original tape and add or strip elements to the song to match the preference of the remixer.  Oftentimes a remix will simply be labeled as a mix.

This will typically exclude any re-cuts of source material and re-recording of your song.